React-native fatal error: module 'RCTDeprecation' in AST file
Hi I'm I have the following error with react-native 0.76.5e Expo 52 when trying to build with fastlane on iOS:

fatal error: module 'RCTDeprecation' in AST file
'/Users/cwi.rafael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
ModuleCache.noindex/37PATSNT0GN4J/RCTDeprecation-2MXEZRVFZYN88.pcm'
(imported by AST file
'/Users/cwi.rafael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Supera-hkjnxpmvfwwyzaeyaemajfjpichw/Build/Intermediates.noinde
x/ArchiveIntermediates/iPlace/PrecompiledHeaders/iPlace-Bridging-Header-swift_2MBCGKNKQ5WY1-clang_37PATSNT0GN4J.pch')
is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load
'/Users/cwi.rafael/Supera/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTDeprecation/RCTDeprecation.modulemap'?

The error occurs when building via fastlane. The strange thing is that Xcode builds it and installs it on the emulator. I tried loading the module directly into the Podfile but it didn't work.
My react-native info:
System:
  OS: macOS 15.1.1
  CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Memory: 669.36 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.18.1
    path: /var/folders/8v/dwlm6vm17dx92xm1jgf2pn3c0000gp/T/yarn--1735505182899-0.9387005554396883/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.22
    path: /var/folders/8v/dwlm6vm17dx92xm1jgf2pn3c0000gp/T/yarn--1735505182899-0.9387005554396883/yarn
  npm:
    version: 7.24.2
    path: ~/Supera/node_modules/.bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.12.02.00
    path: /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.16.1
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 24.1
      - iOS 18.1
      - macOS 15.1
      - tvOS 18.1
      - visionOS 2.1
      - watchOS 11.1
  Android SDK:
    API Levels:
      - "31"
      - "35"
    Build Tools:
      - 29.0.2
      - 30.0.2
      - 34.0.0
      - 35.0.0
    System Images:
      - android-35 | Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom
      - android-35 | Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom
    Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2024.1 AI-241.18034.62.2412.12266719
  Xcode:
    version: 16.1/16B40
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.13
    path: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.7.3
    path: /Users/cwi.rafael/.rbenv/shims/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli":
    installed: 15.1.3
    wanted: latest
  react:
    installed: 18.3.1
    wanted: 18.3.1
  react-native:
    installed: 0.76.5
    wanted: 0.76.5
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false

Any idea to help?
